# Creating ts objects in R with specific days between each registry

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am looking for a method to create `ts` objects in `R` for the following case:

I have a data set of demand of several products where the days between each demand is a specific number of days (***lead time***). These days between demand are not constant as they change depending on the product. Let's put a trivial example:

```
Date       Demand
2016-03-25    2
2016-03-30    0
2016-04-04    5
2016-04-09    3
2016-04-14    4
   ...
2017-12-31    2
```

Here, the *lead time* (inter-demand time or gap between days) is **5 days**. The data starts in `2016-03-25` and ends in `2017-12-31` with `format = %Y-%m-%d`. After reading `ts` documentation, I have tried creating my `ts` object with the following expression:

```
ts(df, frequency = (360/5), start = c(2016, 16))
```

However, I receive the following result:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2016, 17) 
End = c(2018, 4) 
Frequency = 72
```

Which is naturally wrong as the series ends in `2017-12-31` and the output shows `End = c(2018, 4)`, which would be `2018-01-20` in my calculations.

What is the best way to set `ts` in a dataset with these characteristics (having starting date, ending date, and lead time)? What if the lead time wasn't 5 days but 18 days and started in a different initial date the series?

Thanks in advance for your help.

> P.D. I calculated **16** in the parameter `start = c(2016, 16)` by manually
>   counting at what time going from 5th of January I achieved the 25th of
>   March (using 30 days in each month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a few points:

1. The difference between the first and last date in the question is not a multiple of 5 so if your data truly are regularly spaced the data shown in incorrect.  We will assume that the final date is 2017-12-30 to avoid this problem.

   ```
   as.Date("2017-12-31") - as.Date("2016-03-25")
   ## Time difference of 646 days
   ```
2. `ts` is normally not suitable for use with dates.
3. points must be regularly spaced and if they are spaced 5 days apart then we would normally have 365/5 = 73 points per year unless we have a leap year in which the first date is January 1st so let us exclude that possibility.

Based on the above we can use:

```
tt <- ts(dd$Demand, end = c(2017, 365/5), freq = 365/5)
```

where we assume `dd` is as shown in the Note at the end.

The year and cycle position corresponding to each date in `dd` are

```
Year <- as.integer(time(tt))
Cycle <- cycle(tt)
```

A linear regression of as.numeric(dd$Date) vs. as.numeric(time(tt)) and visa versa can be used to translate times.

### Note

Test data `dd` in reproducible form:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016-03-25"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = 5)
dd <- data.frame(Date = dates, Demand = seq_along(dates))
```